# Delete Row in angular

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

```html
<tr *ngFor="let upload of uploads; let i = index">
                <td title="{{upload.documentName}}" class="first_col">{{upload.documentName}}</td>
                <td>{{upload.inputDocumentPassword}}</td>
                <td class="third_col">{{upload.documentFormat}}</td>
                <td>{{upload.uploadTime|date }} <br><span class="time">{{upload.uploadTime|date :'shortTime' }}</span>
                </td>

                <td>{{upload.approvalStatus}}</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="Action">
                      <i class="material-icons md-get_app" (click)="downloadOutput(upload)">get_app</i>
                        <i class="material-icons md-visibility">visibility</i>
                        <i class="material-icons md-picture_as_pdf"  (click)="downloadpdf(upload)">picture_as_pdf</i>
                        <i class="material-icons md-delete"
                        (click)="fileToDelete(upload.documentName)"   onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" >delete</i>
                      <div id="id01" class="w3-modal">
                        <div class="w3-container w3-teal">
                          <div class="Inner-tab">
                            <div class="tittle-box">
                              <label class="warning">WARNING</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="are-you-sure-message">
                              <span>Are you sure you want to delete "{{documenttoDelete}}" file ?</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="btn-tab">
                              <button class="cancle" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'">CANCEL</button>
                              <button class="yes" (click)="delete(upload)" (click)="reload()" >YES</button>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

When I'm trying to delete any row on the page, whichever row I click only 1st row is getting deleted!! I think there is some problem with the loop! Any help would be highly appreciated!

this is my .ts function

```
     delete(userActivity) {
    this.baseService.delete(environment.restPath+'file', userActivity.id).subscribe(
      (data) => {
        this.getPageItems();
      })
    console.log(event);
  }

  getPageItems():void{
    this.baseService.getData(environment.restPath+'file/list/page/'+ this.pageNum+ '?thisUserOnly=true').subscribe(
      (data) => {
        this.total = data.result.totalCount;
        this.userActivityList = [];
        this.userActivityList = data.result.list;
      })
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

call it like :-

```
<button class="yes" (click)="delete(i);reload()" >YES</button>
```

In Typescript :-

```
delete(userActivity) {
this.baseService.delete(environment.restPath+'file', userActivity.id).subscribe(
  (data) => {
    this.getPageItems();
    this.uploads = this.uploads.filter((upload)=> upload.id !== userActivity.id);
  })
console.log(event);
```

}

Comment: but you are not changing your uploads array so how you expect it to delete?

Comment: what would be possible fix?

Comment: In getPageitems() update the array uploads which you are using in html

Comment: @SaiKrishna you are using uploads array in template but you are not changing uploads array on delete. how do you expect it to change?

Comment: @AakashGarg still same! only first row is getting deleted

Comment: can you provide a stackblitz?

Comment: @AakashGarg  https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-3gc5tc

Comment: @SaiKrishna this stackblitz is empty with none of your code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216657/discussion-between-sai-krishna-and-aakash-garg).